# Android - Preferred Activities getting cleared after update

Tags: android, android-preferences

- I'm developing a home screen.
- When I'm launching it for first time, Android pops up a dialog to select default Activity,
  and i set my application as default Activity.
- After that whenever I press Home button, my activity is getting launched.
- So, everything works fine as expected.
- Problem is, after application update, the preferences are getting cleared.
- After application is updated to new version, whenever I press the home button, again Android pops up the same dialog, asking to select the default Activity.

**I think, the default Activity Preferences are cleared automatically after Application update. Is this expected ?**

I found that [PackageManager.addPreferredActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPreferredActivity%28android.content.IntentFilter,%20int,%20android.content.ComponentName%5B%5D,%20android.content.ComponentName%29) can be used to set PreferredActivity programmatically, but its documented as depreceated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the correct behavior, since update of Application involves changes and the user should have right to choose whether or not they want to use the new look and feel of the home launcher application.